# how to do "or" in substring matching for bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell, substring

```
echo `expr "hello" : '\(hi|hello\)'`
echo `expr "hi" : '\(hi|hello\)'`
```

obviously i'm trying to match "hello" and then "hi" to regex hello and hi, but neither matches.

how do i express it properly??

Comment: expr doesn't support extended regex

Comment: This came as a surprise to me, since alternation ('|') is one of the three regular operations (along with concatenation and the Kleene star '*') in formal language theory.

Comment: Also depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  What is the problem you are attempting to solve?  In any event, you should rarely want or need to use `expr` in this day and age.

Comment: The failure of POSIX BRE to support `|` is baffling, since it supports bracket expressions (`[ab]` is just syntactic sugar for `(a|b)`), and it supports back references, which allow non-regular languages to be recognized!

Answer (score 4):

Alternately, plain globs

```
case $str in
    *hi* | *hello*) echo "pleased to meet you"
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

The best option in this simple case is to use [extended globs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching) instead of regular expressions (it'll be more efficient and save you from headaches):

```
string=hello
if [[ $string = @(hi|hello) ]]; then
    echo "String matches"
fi
```

Or (as you're mentioning *substring matches* in the title),

```
string="hello world"
if [[ $string = *@(hi|hello)* ]]; then
    echo "String matches"
fi
```

**Note.** With the `[[` construct, it is not necessary to turn `extglob` on: the [reference manual specifies](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b):

> When the `==` and `!=` operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in [Pattern Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching).

and the rules in the Pattern Matching describe extended globs.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for your edit... but it turns out that `extglob` is not needed here as [seen in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b) about the `[[` keyword: _When the `==` and `!=` operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching._ I was surprised too when I was pointed to this sentence, but it actually makes sense, as these are proper to Bash (in contrast to POSIX shells).

Comment: I did not know that. I tested with extglob explicitly turned off and it does match.

Comment: As far as I can tell (based on reading the release notes; I don't have anything older than 3.2 to try it out), that's been true ever since both `[[...]]` and `extglob` were added to `bash`, way back in `bash` 2.02 :)

Comment: @chepner it was you who pointed this out to me a few days back... thanks `;)`

Comment: @chepner does seem to work since 3.1 (seems that `shopt -s extglob` is needed in 3.0).

Answer (score 1):

A more modern alternative to `expr` is to use [Bash regular expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions):

```
re='hi|hello'
string=hi
[[ $string =~ $re ]] && echo "$string matched"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `|` character is available in extended regular expressions, but `expr` only uses *basic* regular expressions with the `:` operator. [UPDATE: at least in the POSIX version of basic regular expressions; `expr hello '\(hello\|\hi\)'` will work with GNU `expr`, as pointed out by Glenn Jackman]. You would need to rewrite the command as two separate calls to `expr`:

```
$ expr hello : '\(hello\)' || expr hello : '\(hi\)'
hello
$ expr hi : '\(hello\)' || expr hi : '\(hi\)'

hi
$ expr foo : '\(hello\)' || expr foo : '\(hi\)'


$
```

This is still less than ideal, since the failed matches still output an empty string. It's far better to use one of the alternatives presented in the other answers. In particular, the `case` statement is POSIX-compatible and does not rely on any `bash` extensions.

Update: While the regular expression itself cannot use `|`, you *can* combine two `:` expressions within the same call to `expr`:

```
expr hi : '\(hello\)' \| hi : '\(hi\)'
```

When the first `:` fails to find a match, it tries the second. This prevents `expr` from outputting an empty string for the failed first match.

Comment: With BRE, use `\|` for alternation

Comment: I tried; it doesn't work. Alternation isn't mentioned *at all* in the description of BREs, escaped or no.

Comment: (See [the POSIX spec for BREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03).)

Comment: Ugh, GNU and POSIX use different definitions for "basic regular expression". In this case, I think GNU's definition is more sane, at least on the point of including alternation in its definition.

Comment: for posterity, GNU BRE syntax: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/ed-regular-expression-syntax.html